# How to save .env file in windows?

Tags: windows, file-extension

I tried to save file with `.env` file extension but I could not see any `.env` file extension in save as dropdown option.

I also tried to rename it as `.env` but it gets saved as text file (see screenshot) how can I fix this issue ?

[image]

Comment: use a text editor to save `.smthing` files. Like notepad++ or vscode.

Comment: @WilomGfx I am not able to save it I am using sublime text.

Comment: that makes no sense, Sublime should be able to save it just fine...

Comment: in the dropdown, select `All Files`

Comment: @AyushGupta Similarly if I want to save `auth0-config.js.example` so .example file should be saved with same procedure am I right ?

Comment: if you want to give the extension manually, use `All Files`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you use Windows, to save any file with an extension different from the default extension of the tool you are using, You have to select the option which appears like:

`All Files` or `All Files (*.*)` in the **Type of File** dropdown in the save dialogs.

Comment: open the file in notepad , when saving, filename extension .env - choose Save as Type: All Files ( * . * ) from dropdown.

Comment: windows didn't support .env  file like this. just use editors like vs code online or offline app  to create easly

Answer (score 9):

Open your xx.env file with notepad++ and file -> saveas -> rename to .env and save

Answer (score 5):

In windows normally you can not create a file without name. So to create a .env file there are three ways I know...

1. Copy paste from somewhere else
2. If you have installed php then run this command in console `php -r "copy('anyfile.example', '.env');"`
3. Create a txt file called `anything.txt` open `CMD` and find its dir then run `ren anything.txt .env`

Answer (score 2):

Follow the steps below:

1. Open Notepad or Notepad++ and write the context in the file.
   [Notepad workspace screen with some context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brgus.png)
2. Goto **FILE-> SAVE AS**
   [Save as Screen in the notepad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuY9w.png)
3. Select the **All files()**[All files selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kv0Fz.png)
4. Save the file with **.env** in the end[.env extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2uks.png)
5. You've created .env file[.env file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHtRp.png)

I've tried to create .env file in VS Code but it didn't work somehow. If you've any idea please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Steps to create .env file in Windows machine:

1. Open a Notepad and write the credentials inside the file
2. Click on **Save** option and change the **file type** to 'All files'
3. Keep the file name as **.env**
4. Hit **Save**
   Now the file is an .env file. You can also check the file type in File Explorer to confirm.
   *One thing to remember is to put the file inside your Project directory where your code which accesses this .env file is stored.*

Answer (score 0):

You can create a .env file in an IDE directly, like Visual Studio Code.

1.) Just right-click on the directory and create a new file.

2.) Name it as .env

Answer (score -1):

1. You can open notepad
2. Type the information
3. go to file
4. click on save
5. change the file type to (*.*)