# How do I make a plain .env file on Windows 7?

Tags: environment-variables

I'm running Windows 7, and I'm trying to make a .env file. All the tutorials I've seen make it out to be an unnamed file with a .env extention. Whenever I try my hand at making the file, it requires that I give it a name.

Am I missing something, or what do I do to give it no name?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save .env file in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48770643/how-to-save-env-file-in-windows)

Comment: [Danger: Windows 7 is unsupported](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/microsoft-365/windows/end-of-windows-7-support)

Answer (score -1):

You are correct. The env-file will always have the same name: `.env`

For Windows I think the easiest solution is to create a new text file in Explorer by right clicking anywhere and in the context menu click `New > New Text Document`. Then rename your file to be `.env` and confirm that you want to change its extension. You can now use your newly created env-file.